# Power BI Matrix Visual- adding sub category from multiple relations

Tags: powerbi

I am very new to Power BI and a little bit helpless at the moment.

I would like to create a matrix visual for following model:

User(User,HD,HC,...)
RoleToUser(Username,Role)
Role(Role,...)
Transaction(Transaction,HD,HC,...)
RoleToTransaction(Role,Transaction)

[Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv6MC.png)

HC/HD just contains an X (true/false)

Creating a matrix with Role in cloumns , Transactions in rows and a count on a field of RoleToTransaction as value worked fine.

In the next step I want to add the user as a sub category under role, to show all users for the selected row with a drill down. After I added User(User) to the matrix columns I get an error if I try to drill down from Roles.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Hello Luca. a user can have many roles. that's the logic after checking your model view. Please change places, namely, put roles as subcategory under user. If that doesn't solve your problem, please share what error It produces.

Comment: Hey Ozan, thanks for your answer. Its a many to many relationship. Thats the reason why there is a extra table (RoleToUser). Same goes for  transaction and role.

Comment: Okay. dear Luca Please tell me which tables do the [role] and [user] columns come from ?